# How was the dwarf character in Apporva sagothargal Appu depicted?

Tags: film-techniques, make-up

In the 1989 Indian film, [Apporva sagothargal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoorva_Sagodharargal_%281989_film%29) actor kamal hassan plays a double role - one of a normal man and another one of a dwarf. How was kamal Hassan displayed as a dwarf in the movie ?

Comment: Which version of the film? What do you mean how he was made? How they made him appear as a dwarf? How was he conceived? It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: How they made him appear as a dwarf?How was kamal Hassan displayed as a dwarf in the movie ?

Comment: I get your question because I have seen the movie. I have edited for everyone to understand.

Comment: @Hariharan: Thanks for clarification from both of you. I've retracted my close vote and upvoted question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number of techniques were involved for the portrayal of a normal man as a dwarf on the screen. For some shots the actor folded hi legs from feet to knees. For some static scenes his legs were hidden inside a trench. Special shoes had to be used when the character was shown walking. The movie's director has explained it all [here](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-national/tp-andhrapradesh/singeetam-reveals-secret-behind-kamals-dwarf-role/article1311684.ece).